# I can't get more than 8 different colors using OpenGL

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, rgb, glut

I made a simple C program that creates a window filled with pixels with specified colors.
I'm using the freeglut library with a gcc compiler in OpenSuse. I use the glDrawPixels function and store the pixel data in the floating point format: 3 floats per pixel. The code seems to work fine with basic colors like {1.0,0.0,0.0}, {1.0,1.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0} and so on. But it doesn't seem to draw colors with values between 0 and 1. For example, the color {1.0, 0.5, 0.0} should be orange, but the code draws it as red instead.

Here's some fragments of the code:

```
void my_pixel(void)
{
    float dat[200*200*3];
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // computing dat

    glDrawPixels(200,200,GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT,dat);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDispalyMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200,200);
    glutInitWindowSize(200,200);
    glutCreateWindow("AlexViewer");
    glutDisplayFunc(my_pixel);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Kids these days. In my CGA days, we were perfectly happy - four colours suffice.

Comment: +1 Haha... well CG was in its infancy then, the kids were spoiled by the elders

Comment: Should be ok. How do you fill `dat`?

Comment: @Sasha: Just to verify if you've setup the GLUT window right, how about setting the clear colour to orange and see if that works first?

Comment: yeah it works that way, now the background color is orange

Comment: Side note: if you are using `glutSwapBuffers();`, probably you meant to initialize the window with `GLUT_DOUBLE`?

Comment: thanks for your replies, I solved the problem. I defined the rgb color values as integers instead of floats. Silly mistake.